# How safe is cookie authentication/authorization in asp.net?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, cookies, session-cookies

How safe is Cookie based Authentication/Authorization in ASP.NET C#? Take a look at the example below, don't worry about password hashing, is this a secure/semi-secure method, or sufficient enough to prevent attacks and exploits against a web application? would you change anything in this code?

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
    {
        var user = await _context.UsersTableTest.FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.UserName == Username);

        if (user != null && user.PasswordHash == Password)
        {
            var claims = new List<Claim>
        {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.UserName),
            new Claim("UserDepartment", user.UserDepartment) // Assuming you have a Department property in the user model
        };

            var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(
                claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

            var authProperties = new AuthenticationProperties
            {
                // Set additional properties if needed
            };

            await HttpContext.SignInAsync(
                CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity),
                authProperties);

            return RedirectToPage("/Index"); // Redirect to a protected page
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
            return Page();
        }
    }
```

Comment: It seems that your code currently works, and you are looking to improve it. Generally these questions are too opinionated for this site, but you might find better luck at [CodeReview.SE](//codereview.stackexchange.com/tour). Remember to read [their requirements](//codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) as they are a bit more strict than this site.